# Best way to re-populate EditTexts from database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-room, android-livedata

I'm making an app with a lot of user input from edittexts stored in a Room database with an attached TextWatcher. When a fragment is opened, I want to repopulate the EditTexts with the values that have previously been stored. In order to do this, I am currently observing LiveData from the Database once, and removing the observer once the EditText is re-populated.

This works well the first time I open each fragment. The problem that I'm having is that if I make a quick change in one fragment -- deleting the text, for instance -- and navigate away, then back again, the EditText re-populates with old data instead of the newest change.

I know from the Database Inspector that the new value is being stored, but when the EditTexts are re-populated, the TextWatcher causes the old value to be stored in the database again, overwriting the new value. So I'm guessing that the issue is a delay in the Database updating the LiveData, and the EditTexts being re-populated before the data is actually returned from the Database.

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Should I be using SavedInstanceState instead, and somehow only using LiveData on the first load? I'm not currently using a repository -- I'm teaching myself Kotlin and haven't learned about them yet. Would that solve this issue? I have a lot of fragments and a lot of EditTexts, so I'm trying to find the cleanest way to deal with this.

I hope this is clear. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a TextWatcher on your EditText that updates the database with every change/keystroke? If so, this must have something to do with when you attach/detach the TextWatcher.

Comment: That's correct! Sorry if I wasn't clear. I re-populate the EditTexts before attaching the TextWatcher, but I never detach the TextWatcher. (I keep getting an error when I try to, and I wasn't sure if it was necessary.) If my logic is right, I think detaching could solve the problem of the database values being overwritten, but not the problem of the old LiveData value being used to re-populate the EditTexts? Or am I missing something?